# Monster hunters arms and armor

Tags: magic, medieval

Let us say that this group of people are very fit both muscularly and in cardio.  We have created a shield already.  Many of the things they fight are very large but not always fast.  In general what would be the best arms and armor available with medieval and early renaissance technology for fighting large thick-skinned creatures.

Edit: These creatures can grow up to the size and weight of an elephant but the height and length of the creature varies.
Horses are available in this consideration.

Comment: If the monster is extremely strong or large, it becomes more beneficial to have lighter armor and avoid the hits, rather than take the hits (especially if they are 1 hit kills). I would suggest leather armor over metal armor to allow your group to dodge and avoid hits.

Comment: you make a good point perhaps they could be horse mounted and keep it at a range and bombard it with ranged weapons

Comment: How large are we talking? Elephant or house or bigger? And do they fight in a group or is this supposed to be one on one with the monsters?

Comment: i think i answered what i needed to so far in the edits, thankyou

Comment: There is no best arm and armor you can have. It will vary a lot depending on the groups composition, the monster and why they are attacking the monster in the first place. You can try draw inspiration from MMORPG games and boss raids.

Comment: Probably canons and or rifles.

Comment: Cannons and primitive firearms appeared around the same time as the Renaissance began.  If you don't want them, you should be clearer about your time scale or technological progress.

Answer (score 5):

**Spears**

Almost every example of dangerous creatures that humans have hunted (in the given technological era) were hunted with spears or missile weapons (generally bows).

Despite what computer games might tell you weapons like swords, axes, maces etc. aren't much use because you need to get too close to use them.

If hunting a boar was dangerous and required a special spear you can be sure that hunting an elephant sized monster will also require a spear. Spears allow you to strike with reasonable force from far away, they can be used defensively so the animal runs on to it using its own momentum to drive the spear in, they are cheap and easy to make and also easy to learn to use.

Missile weapons like bows are also useful but it would depend on how thick the creature's hide is and how fast it is. If it's a lumbering giant you might be able to put enough arrows in it while staying at a safe distance to kill it, but a faster creature might get within attack range after only a few shots.

Comment: Various versions of spears can be missile weapons.

Comment: Swords,axes,maces. they were more for fighting human troops

Answer (score 3):

Some sort of [Scorpions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorpio_(weapon)) (the artillery that the Romans used), that act as harpoons (that we assume can pierce the monster's skin) and hold them in place or least least slow them down.